# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth only 2 connections possible with sixad

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, ps3

after updating from 16.04 to 18.04, I can only successfully connect 2 of my 4 sixaxis controllers to my system, using sixad.
It simply only accepts the first two controllers I turn on.

Updating to bluez 5.50 did not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: device is a Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can be fixed by forcing the bluetooth devices to act as a master device. Maybe the bluetooth stack/hardware only supports 2 slave connections? By default, my controllers connect as a slave device on Ubuntu 18.04. So I do the following:

1. connect 2 controllers regularly
2. 2x '#hcitool sr [mac] master' for connected devices
3. connect remaining 2 controllers